# Minimum over a dense subset

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, vector-spaces

Let $X$ denote a vector space and let $S \subset X$ denote a dense subset of $X$.
Does the following result hold?
\begin{equation*}
\min_{x \in X} F(x) = \min_{y \in S} F(y).
\end{equation*}
Do we need some assumptions on the function or the vector space? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Do we need some assumptions on the function or the vector space?" Yes, you need a topology.

Comment: Yes, you need restrictions on $F$ to have this hold. A trivial counterexample is the characteristic function on $S$.

Comment: @amsmath OP has a topology since they have a notion of $S$ being dense in $X$.

Comment: @DonThousand But OP doesn't write this. They only have a vector space.

Comment: What does density mean sin a topology?

Answer (score 1):

Provided $F$ is continuous, then we can conclude
$$\inf_{x \in X} F(x) = \inf_{x \in S} F(x). \tag{$\star$}$$
Clearly
$$\inf_{x \in X} F(x) \le \inf_{x \in S} F(x),$$
as the right hand side is the infimum of a subset of the left hand side. Further, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $y \in X$ such that
$$\inf_{x \in X} F(x) \le F(y) < \inf_{x \in X} F(x) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Since $F$ is continuous at $y$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\|z - y\| < \delta &\implies |F(z) - F(y)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
&\implies F(z) < F(y) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
&\implies F(z) < \inf_{x \in X} F(x) + \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Since $S$ is dense in $X$, there exists some $z \in S$ such that $\|z - y\| < \delta$, and hence
$$\inf_{x \in S} F(x) \le F(z) < \inf_{x \in X} F(x) + \varepsilon.$$
This holds for all $\varepsilon$, so $(\star)$ holds.

Now, if we assume that both the infima are achieved, then we get
$$\min_{x \in X} F(x) = \min_{x \in S} F(x).$$
However, be warned that $\min_{x \in X} F(x)$ existing doesn't necessarily imply $\min_{x \in S} F(x)$. For example, $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} : x \mapsto x^2$ achieves a minimum at $0$, but does not achieve a minimum on the dense set $\Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.